# Notice: Undefined index for all fields in my database

Tags: php, database, undefined

I am having problems with a script, it was created for an assignment a few years ago in Uni, it worked fine then and I did not get this notice, now for every field I am getting a "Notice: Undefined index".

I've read that it is something to do with failing to declare variables and I need to sue an isset ? But I am still unsure how to implement it in the code.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
require 'server.php';

$results = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM details WHERE id = :id');
$results->execute(array(
     ':id' => $_GET['id'],
     ));

if (isset($_POST['submit'] )) header("Location: template/header.php"); {
    $update = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE details SET firstname = :firstname, surname = :surname, houseno = :houseno, street = :street, town= :town,
           county = :county, postcode = :postcode,  mobile = :mobile, nickname = :nickname, website = :website,
           homephone = :homephone WHERE id = :id');
    $update->execute(array(
        ':id' => $_POST['id'],
        ':firstname' => $_POST['firstname'],
        ':surname' => $_POST['surname'],
        ':houseno' => $_POST['houseno'],
        ':street' => $_POST['street'],
        ':town' => $_POST['town'],
        ':county' => $_POST['county'],
        ':postcode' => $_POST['postcode'],
        ':mobile' => $_POST['mobile'],
        ':nickname' => $_POST['nickname'],
        ':website' => $_POST['website'],
        ':homephone' => $_POST['homephone'],    
    ));

    $row = $results->fetch();
}

require 'template/header.php';
?>
```

Any ideas on how to fix the problem?  Image here:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10062971/phpnotice.JPG

Comment: From next time select the whole code block and press `Ctrl+K`.

Answer (score 0):

You code does not make any sense: When `$_POST['submit'] )` is set, you redirect to another page so the code that uses the `POST` variables will run when `$_POST['submit'] )` is not set.

This is what it looks like to php:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'] ))
{
   header("Location: template/header.php");
}

$update = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE details SET firstname = :firstname, surname = :surname, houseno = :houseno, street = :street, town= :town,
       county = :county, postcode = :postcode,  mobile = :mobile, nickname = :nickname, website = :website,
       homephone = :homephone WHERE id = :id');
$update->execute(array(
    ':id' => $_POST['id'],
    ':firstname' => $_POST['firstname'],
    ':surname' => $_POST['surname'],
    ':houseno' => $_POST['houseno'],
    ':street' => $_POST['street'],
    ':town' => $_POST['town'],
    ':county' => $_POST['county'],
    ':postcode' => $_POST['postcode'],
    ':mobile' => $_POST['mobile'],
    ':nickname' => $_POST['nickname'],
    ':website' => $_POST['website'],
    ':homephone' => $_POST['homephone'],    
));

$row = $results->fetch();
```

What exactly is the `header` call for?

By the way, you probably want something like this:

```
require 'server.php';

if (isset($_POST['submit'] ))
{
  $update = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE details SET firstname = :firstname, surname = :surname, houseno = :houseno, street = :street, town= :town,
       county = :county, postcode = :postcode,  mobile = :mobile, nickname = :nickname, website = :website,
       homephone = :homephone WHERE id = :id');
  $update->execute(array(
    ':id' => $_POST['id'],
    ':firstname' => $_POST['firstname'],
    ':surname' => $_POST['surname'],
    ':houseno' => $_POST['houseno'],
    ':street' => $_POST['street'],
    ':town' => $_POST['town'],
    ':county' => $_POST['county'],
    ':postcode' => $_POST['postcode'],
    ':mobile' => $_POST['mobile'],
    ':nickname' => $_POST['nickname'],
    ':website' => $_POST['website'],
    ':homephone' => $_POST['homephone'],    
  ));

  // show message or something
}
else
{
  // normal get request, nothing posted
  $results = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM details WHERE id = :id');
  $results->execute(array(':id' => $_GET['id'],
     ));
  $row = $results->fetch();

  // show rest of the page
}
```

Comment: Won't that do it all in one go though? The code is supposed to bring the detail of a certain DB entry up and populate the HTML fields (I did not include the HTML code), then when I submit it modifies the fields in the database.

Comment: @Will Thompson You can do it all in the same page / script, but you need to distinguish between a `POST` request (`if (isset($_POST['submit'] ))`) and a normal `GET` request (when the page is initially opened.

Comment: It is all in the same page, the code appears to work just it's getting those "undefined index" errors.

Comment: @Will Thompson See the second part of my answer.

Comment: I tried that code but the undefined index is still there and it won't get any results from the DB.

Comment: @Will Thompson See my edit / the code how it should be (more or less...).

Answer (score 0):

Use `isset` to check if they exist before using any index on `$_POST` or `$_GET`.

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $results->execute(array(
    ':id' => $_GET['id'],
  ));
}

...

':id' => isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : '',
':firstname' => isset($_POST['firstname']) ? $_POST['firstname'] : '',
// and so on
...
```